# Alternative to isset(user_input) in php

Tags: php, validation, isset

I was wondering whether is another way to check if a variable coming from user input is set and not null, besides (the obvious choice) isset().
In some cases, we may not be using $_POST to get the value, but some similar custom function. isset() can not be used on the result of a function call, so an alternative way to perform the same check must be made. Now, isset() verifies two things:

1. Whether the value was set.
2. Whether the value is null. But there is some difference between assigning a variable the null value ( `$variable = NULL;` ) and getting a null value due to empty input fields. Or at least so I read.

So, is there a good way of checking both these requirements without using isset() ?

Comment: Could you give an example of *some similar function*?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The equivalent of `isset($var)` for a function return value is `func() === null`.

`isset` basically does a `!== null` comparison, without throwing an error if the tested variable does not exist. This is a non-issue for function return values, since a) functions must exist (or PHP will exit with a fatal error) and b) a function *always* returns something, at least `null`. So all you really need to do is to check for `null`, no `isset` necessary.

I've written about this extensively here: [The Definitive Guide To PHP's isset And empty](http://kunststube.net/isset/).

---

Beyond this, it depends on what exactly you want to check:

- test if a key was submitted via GET/POST: `isset($_POST['key'])`
- test if there's a value and whether it's not `== false`: `!empty($_POST['key'])`
- test if it's a non-empty string: `isset($_POST['key']) && strlen($_POST['key'])`
- perhaps much more complex validations: [`filter_input`](http://www.php.net/filter_input)

Answer (score 2):

Here are some options...

PHP 7.4+ : null coalescing assignment operator

```
$variable ??= '';
```

PHP 7.0+ : null coalescing operator

```
$variable = $var ?? '';
```

PHP 5.3+ : ternary operator

```
isset($variable) ?: $var = '';
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way is isset but if you insist ... try `empty()` and `strlen()` Function to check wether it is empty or string lenghth is bigger than so many characters.
`strlen()` returns a number, length of the variable passed to it.
`empty()` checks if it has character in it or if it is null. with `empty()` you have to be becareful because some functions return `0` or `false` which is not considered empty.

```
if(!empty($var))....
```

OR

```
if(strlen($var)>2)...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `!empty()` in place of `isset()`
the function `!empty()` works for both `isset()` and check whether the value of any string is not null, 0 or any empty string.
I usually prefer `!empty()` whenever I need to compare variable existence or in terms of its value.

Comment: This will catch much more than an `isset` check; it's not necessarily an equivalent replacement.

Answer (score -1):

I do it in most cases like this:

```
$v = my_func();
if (isset($v) and $v) {
 ...
}
```

Comment: 1) No need for `isset` for a variable which you know exists (because you just set it). 2) A shorthand for `isset($v) && $v` is `!empty($v)`. 3) Because of 1), you really just want `if ($v)` here.

Comment: You right. I use the above if it's an entry in a array, which I don't know if set. I was not totally awake when writing this :) Thank you for !empty($v).

Comment: @deceze Actually, I thought the same (that user input is normally set). However, mistakes can be made, like forgetting to create the field or checking with the wrong name.

Comment: @amygrimaldi In *this particular example*, the variable `$v` **is being set**. Right there, one line before the `isset` check. There's absolutely no need to use `isset` for this particular variable `$v` here. All you need to worry about is the variable's *value*, which you can check perfectly fine using just `if ($v)` (meaning `if ($v == true)`), or whatever other particular check you need to do.

Comment: @deceze I did not understand to which particular example are you referring? If you mean my case, I may have it set for now and accidentally delete / modify it later. Or maybe someone else working with this code in the future may mess it up. I get the point that as long as you write proper code, there is no need to check for it. But no one can guarantee that there won't be mistakes. My code might change, or the code of other users reading this thread might be different. And anyone reading that you don't need isset may forget to make sure that the variable exists, and just do without it.

Comment: @amygrimaldi I mean in this particular example of this answer under which this comment is written. – And what you cite is exactly why you want to avoid `isset` as much as possible: to have alarm bells ring when someone, anyone, messes up the code. If some piece of code *requires and expects* certain variables to exist, then other code needs to make sure they exist. If the code just silently dies because some other code didn't set some variables properly, you'll have a very hard time debugging such issues without *"Notice: undefined variable"* errors.